# xamarin offline data sync with filters

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, data-synchronization, offlineapps

I'm trying to develop using Xamarin Forms a logistic application that has a central Database which stores data coming from multiple warehouses.
 I would like to get an offline sync features to my devices only with data related to specific warehouses. (see Jpg)

Is there any framework or sample that I can use as guideline ?

Regards

[Example Jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5uQY.jpg)

Comment: Some relevant discussion on https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5719/sync-sqlite-with-sql-server-merge-replication.

Comment: Hi Matteo, I'm working on a similar problem from last September. I can't use SQL (Azure or Standalone) and I created my sync procedures. It's a mess. If you need, I can share with you same info about it.

Comment: @Enrico Can you please share your code to me at ishworkhnl[at]gmail[dot]com. I am also building xamarin.form application which requires offline data storage and synchronization when connected.

Answer (score 1):

there are a few samples out there:

**Xamarin Evolve 2016 App  by James Montemagno**

- [Blog Entry](https://blog.xamarin.com/browse-through-the-evolve-2016-mobile-app-source-code/)
- [Source on Github](https://github.com/xamarinhq/app-evolve)

Depends on [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/) as backend but even if you don't want to use it, it is a good sample to look at.

**Todo with sql-database**

- [Source on Github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Todo)

This doesn't have a backend but is a good example how to use a sqlite-database to store data for offline usage.

**Todo Backends**

- [Source on Github](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/WebServices)

Versions of the Todo App with different backends e.g. Azure, WCF, ASMX, ... 
but without Offline-Sync

Comment: any idea how to filter the data i'm getting synched from the central Database ? (just in case I dont want all the content of a table to be synched to my mobile)

Comment: Matteo, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Matteo,
you could implement a server extension like this

```
public static class ItemExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<WarehouseItem> WarehouseFilter(this IQueryable<WarehouseItem> query, string WarehouseId)
    {
        return query.Where(item => item.WarehouseId.Equals(WarehouseId));
    }
}
```

and then  implement it as

```
public IQueryable<WarehouseItem> GetAllWarehouseItems()
{
    return Query().WarehouseFilter(WarehouseId);
}

public SingleResult<WarehouseItem> GetWarehouseItem(string id)
{
   return new SingleResult<WarehouseItem>(Lookup(id).Queryable.WarehouseFilter(WarehouseId));
}
```

A great reference for stuff like this is Adrian Hall online tutorial
https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure

Hope it helps!